# Excel file locked after opening in Microsoft Data Report Designer

Tags: excel, vb6, report

I develop an application in VB6 and my data source is Excel 2007. And I have created 2 reports in [Microsoft Data Report Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733655%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

My program is working. I can save data (update)in excel file and view existing data via VB6. And I have written code to backup (copy paste) the excel file in another folder. This is also working as I wanted.

But after I open or view the DataReports, I cant save the data in the Excel and backup the excel file. Then I will have to close the application to update and backup excel sheet.

When I try to save data in Excel file after viewing the report I receive the message

> The excel file already exists

When I try to backup after viewing and closing the report I receive the error message

> Run time error 70" Permission denied

Need help please.

Comment: Only one application can have the workbook open at a time.  I am a bit confused as to what you have to close to update and backup.  Is your app called "DataReport"?

Comment: Thank you Joe for the reply. I have to close my application(VB6 program) and open it again to update and backup. "DataReport" is not my application name. The reports are created in Microsoft "DataReport".

Comment: Are you calling `wb.Close` each time you finish working with the workbook (where `wb` is the handle to the Workbook object)?

Comment: Yes, I close the workbook and clear the memory. I think in this case I have to diconnect the 'Dataenvironment' after display the report.

Comment: I solved this problem and my application works. I close the DataEnvironment connection after the report is created;                           (DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1.Close
DataEnvironment1.Connection1.Close )   and open it before view or create the report;    (DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1.Open
DataEnvironment1.Connection1.Open   )